# What is tModel in Binding template under UDDI?

Tags: web-services, soap, uddi

I found a tag called 'tModel' under the 'binding' tag of the UDDI. Can somebody explain to me what is the use of tModel?

Answer (score 0):

Tmodel  = technical model.  It's basically a key name value set that you can use to attach additional data to any uddi structure